# Chrome keeps opening text files instead of using Text Editor

Tags: google-chrome

So I have a YAML file, and it keeps opening in chrome unless I use `open with other application` > `Text Editor`, and even `Open with Text Editor` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change the default application for text files by right clicking on said document, select `Properties` > `Open With` > Select your desired text editor from the program list > `Set as default`

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is ALREADY set to Text Editor, but Chrome keeps opening it.